# How to create new Mercurial branch in VS Code with mrcrowl plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mercurial

I have the Visual Studio Code v1.51.0 with the mrcrowl.hg plugin installed. I have been looking for a tutorial how to create new Mercurial branch. Can anybody give me an advice how to do that or redirect me to some information source? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found how to do that:

1. `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open command pallete in Visual Studio
2. write `Hg: Create branch`
3. fill in name of the branch